# Android recreate() method and bundle

Tags: android, android-activity

I would like to know what would happen if I were to call `recreate()` from an `activity` that receives a `bundle`. The scenario would be that the `activity` would load content that is dependent on the content of the `bundle`. If the `recreate()` method were to be called, would the content of the `bundle` be lost or would it still exist?

**EDIT** With `recreate()`, I put a `Log.d()` in the `onCreate()` method and the `bundle` appeared to still have the data. My activity was still destroyed, any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just ended up using `SharedPreferences`